# What are all the structural isomers of a tertiary amine with the sum formula C6H15N?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, amines

According to the solutions there exist 7 different structural isomers 'containing 3 degree amines' for the molecular formula  $\ce{C_6H_{15}N}$

I tried and made a few, here are those

[image]

I have been trying since an hour and all I made were the repetitions of these 5 only. Could anyone suggest me the remaining 2?

Comment: There is a methyl ethyl propyl amine and methyl ethyl isopropyl amine .

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! Find out about the site by taking the [tour] and about formatting in the [help]. If you get helpful answers, please consider accepting one.

Answer (score 2):

*Please note that this is just a visualization of the comment given by **LDC3**!*

Here are the two missing isomers:

[image: C6H15N]

Comment: The drawings were made using `BKChem` under Linux. The program is in the repositories of all major Linux distributions, There also seem to be Windows and OSX ports at [BKChem](http://bkchem.zirael.org/) which I haven't tried. The program was initially written by Beda Kosata and is currently maintained by Reinis Danne. Sources are available from her repository on [gitorious](https://gitorious.org/bkchem).